# Looping TGauge with timer

Tags: delphi, gauge

I want to replace my progress bar with gauge. Here is version on progress bar:

```
procedure TForm1.tmr1Timer(sender: TObject);
begin
  pb0.Position := (pb0.Position + 1) mod pb0.Max;
end;
```

And this is on gauge

```
procedure TForm1.tmr1Timer(sender: TObject);
begin
  gauge.MinValue := 0;
  gauge.MaxValue := 100;
  gauge.Progress := gauge.Progress + 1;
end;
```

How to make it start over every time it reach 100 ?
As i tried with button to test, i can not make it looping just like on progress bar.

```
procedure TForm1.btn6Click(sender: TObject);
begin
  tmr1.Enabled := not tmr1.Enabled;
  begin
    gauge.Progress := 0;
    tmr1.Enabled := True
  end;
  if Form1.gauge.Progress = 100 then // is this correct ?
  // what to do to make it looping ?
end;
```

How to make same the function on gauge as replacement for progress bar + timer above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way. Just use the different property names for `TGauge` (and remove the setting of `MinValue` and `MaxValue` from the timer event):

```
procedure TForm1.tmr1Timer(sender: TObject);
begin
  gauge.Progress := (gauge.Progress + 1) mod (gauge.MaxValue - gauge.MinValue);;
end;
```

@DavidHeffernan points out in a comment that my calculation will never reach a full `100%` value, and suggests an alternative:

```
gauge.Progress := gauge.MinValue + (gauge.Progress + 1) mod 
             (gauge.MaxValue - gauge.MinValue + 1);
```

It has different issues: the progress display does not start at `0`, and it increments in steps of 2. However, it indeed does reach `100%`.

As @TLama pointed out in a comment, neither of the above work if the `MinValue` can be negative.

---

This calculation has no issues (loops from MinValue to MaxValue, and both can be negative) if `MinValue < MaxValue`

```
gauge.Progress := gauge.MinValue + 
                  ( gauge.Progress + 1 - gauge.MinValue ) mod 
                  ( gauge.MaxValue - gauge.MinValue + 1 );
```

Comment: This code only works if MinValue is 0. It will also never set Progress equal to MaxValue. You want MinValue + (Progress+1) mod (MaxValue-MinValue+1)

Comment: @David: It worked in the XE5 VCL test app I ran it on, exactly as posted, with the default `MinValue = 0` and `MaxValue = 100` (I set the timer to 250ms for testing). Since the intent of the question is to wrap back to zero and start over, never setting progress to MaxValue doesn't appear to be a problem; if it hit 100%, it would be done and there would be no point in looping back to 0, right? You're probably right about MinValues other than 0; I'll update shortly (in the middle of something in about 2 minutes).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Just retested (and tested your alternative), both with MinValue = 0 and 1, TTimer interval at 250, XE5. Your version incremented by 2 instead of 1, and stopped updating at 99%. Mine incremented by 1, and stopped updating at 99%, with either MinValue. I can post the code I tested if you'd like.

Comment: @Ken, let's have `Min = -5`, `Max = 5` and `Pos = 5`. You'd get `(5 + 1) mod (5 - (-5))` which results to 6, but you should get -5 to get to the beginning of the progress.

Comment: @TLama: You're right. Neither my version or David's works properly with a negative MinValue. I'll note that in my answer. Thanks. (I never considered a negative MinValue, because I always use a ProgressBar to indicate a percentage of completion, which is always expressed as a positive. If I had to deal with a negative MinValue, I'd do the percentage calculation first, and then update progress.)

Comment: I just edited your answer and add a working solution without any issues

Comment: @SirRufo: I can confirm it works with `-5` and `5`. Nice. Thanks!